# How to remove a imageview from a LinearLayout by position

Tags: java, android

I have button inside of LinearLayout which takes photos from gallery and displays at that same LinearLayout :

[image]

The problem now is if I want to remove some images just by the tapping the image, that is my current code :

```
public void AddNewImages(Context context,Bitmap bitmap){
    ImageView img = new ImageView(context);
    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    linearImages.addView(img);
    bitmapArray.add(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: Please Provide full information what you want to achieve? You are saying you want to remove some images. But your code says some different story.

Comment: As you are adding images to L.Lyt.  for each image view call `setTag(position)` and on tap of it `getTag()` and remove it from L.Lyt. `LLyt.removeViewAt(postion);` or `LLyt.removeView(view);`

Comment: So the position is a index to increase each time that a image is created?

Answer (score 1):

Try this listener:

```
img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        linearImages.removeView(v);
    }
});
```